# How can I change the progress bar class dynamically in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some simple progress bars like this :

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 35%">
    Youtube Connection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 35%">
        Verify Information <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The color of the second progress bar is green. 
I have a button

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button" onclick="changeColor();">Next Step</a>
```

I want the function `changeColor()` change the color of the second navbar (green) `class="progress-bar-success "` to `class="progress-bar-info"`

I give you an exemple :

http://bootply.com/102834

How can i do that ?

Comment: Hey Martialp, check my answer below. Hope I helped.

Comment: simple, perfect for me ! thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved with a big of jQuery magic. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n67LM/7/) if you are excited.

**HTML**

You first add the class `.change` to your button for the callback.

```
<a class="change btn btn-lg btn-primary pagination-centered">Next Step</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
   $( ".change" ).click(function() {
  $('.progress_2').removeClass("progress-bar-success");
    $('.progress_2').addClass("progress-bar-info");
});
```

Shorter way of achieving this in 3 lines:

```
$( ".change" ).click(function() {
  $('.progress_2').removeClass("progress-bar-success").addClass("progress-bar-info");
});
```

**Result**

[image]